# How to extract strange XML-table via Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, extract, xmltable

I have following code in a xml-file and I want to extract the table of the xml file via python:

```
"....

<Test_input_data>
    <web_pins type="list" orientation="column">
        <web_pin_id type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="1"/>
        <pin_center_node type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="2"/>
        <journal_center_node type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="3"/>
         1  1012  5011
         2  2012  5012
         3  3012  5013
    </web_pins>
</Test_input_data>

...."
```

That means I want to extract separately these lines and each value:

```
  1  1012  5011
  2  2012  5012
  3  3012  5013
```

But I don't know how to access these values, maybe YOU may help me?

Comment: Help yourself by using a Python XML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup), here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

xml = """<Test_input_data>
    <web_pins type="list" orientation="column">
        <web_pin_id type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="1"/>
        <pin_center_node type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="2"/>
        <journal_center_node type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="3"/>
         1  1012  5011
         2  2012  5012
         3  3012  5013
    </web_pins>
</Test_input_data>"""
soup = bs(xml)
tag = soup.find("web_pins")
text = tag.text #Here you get your text!
##P.S. you can also use:
soup.web_pins.text
```

---

Also, you may want to look at standart's library [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).
Again, here is an example:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    data = ""
    search_tag = None
    grab_data = False

    def feed(self, data, tag_to_search_for):

        self.search_tag = tag_to_search_for
        HTMLParser.feed(self, data)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):

        if tag == self.search_tag:
            self.grab_data = 1

    def handle_data(self, data):

        if self.grab_data:
            self.data = data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):

        if tag == self.search_tag:
            self.grab_data = 0

xml = """<Test_input_data>
    <web_pins type="list" orientation="column">
        <web_pin_id type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="1"/>
        <pin_center_node type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="2"/>
        <journal_center_node type="column_definition" data_type="int" index="3"/>
         1  1012  5011
         2  2012  5012
         3  3012  5013
    </web_pins>
</Test_input_data>"""

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(xml, "web_pins")
print parser.data #Ta-daa!
```

Comment: First one worked for me, second not, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). (of course, other parsers exist, such as [lxml](http://lxml.de/))

Using it is very simple, create an Element instance from the XML by using [XML](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XML) function and you are ready to go.